# C# Windows forms - qualquer cor fora do for acionar evento dos pictures boxx

Tags: winforms, picturebox

Bom dia pessoal.

Por favor, eu tenho um formulario em Windows forms, com dois Picrutes box, e gostaria que, quando a alguma cor de alguma aplicação externa (onde esses pictures box estivessem em cima) mudassem de cor, acionassem um evento, indicando essa mudança de cor.

Eu consegui fazer o acionamento do evento, mas de forma manual (movendo com o mouse, via evento OnMouseDown), agora gostaria de saber como fazer via ação externa, se alguém puder ajudar desde já fico agradecido.[Imagem do form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3XVA.png)